# Error when modelling: contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, linear-regression

Trying to answer this step in my assignment

"Fit a model predicting total daily bike rentals from season, year, whether the day is holiday or not, whether the day is a workingday or not, the weather category, temperature, feeling temperature, humidity and windspeed, as well as the interaction between at least one numerical and one categorical variable."

Here is what I have entered, and below is the error I continue to get

```
{r}full_model <- lm(cnt ~ season+yr+holiday+workingday+weathersit + atemp_raw + temp + hum+ windspeed + season:atemp_raw, dcbikeshare)
glance(full_model)
tidy(coef(full_model))
```

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :
> contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels